# Hidden input are not sending something via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sometime i am getting error about missing post data from Ajax, this isn't happen every-time and i cant understand why i am getting error message like this in my controller

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: product_id

Template

```
<ul class="block-price">
    <li<?php if (!$stock): ?> style="display:none" <?php endif; ?>>
        <i onclick="priceUpdate('plus');"  class="fa fa-minus price-minus" aria-hidden></i>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
        <i onclick="priceUpdate('minus');"  class="fa fa-plus price-plus" aria-hidden></i>
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
function priceUpdate(type) {
    var i = parseInt($('#input-quantity').val());

    if(type == 'plus'){
        f = Number(i + 1).toString();
    }else{
        f = Number(i - 1).toString();
    }

    $('input[name="quantity"]').val(''+f+'').trigger('change')
}
$('#product').on('input change', 'input, select', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=priceUpdate',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {

        }
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function priceUpdate(){
  $data = [
   'cart_id'        => false,
   'product_id'     => $this->request->post['product_id'], (error message is this lane)
   'quantity'       => $quantity
  ];
}
```

Comment: You can't send a `jQuery` object as AJAX data. You need to extract the values from those elements via something like [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @Phil extracting the values is happen in $this->request->post

Comment: I mean client-side. You need to extract the values from the HTML form elements in order to pass them along in your AJAX request

Comment: @ivan  based on you comment on my answer you need to put all above html code inside `<form></form>`tag and then direct use `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()` of jquery to post all data